# Cart Using Session Item removal and total price

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart, cart

I'm working on a shopping cart using session array, here is my code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))  
{
if(isset($_POST["item"])){
    if(isset($_POST["item"]["itemsize"]) && ($_POST["item"]["itemsize"] == "small")){
        if((sizeof($_POST["item"]['itemgreen'])<=5) && (sizeof($_POST["item"]['itemblue'])<=1)){
            $_SESSION["item"][] = $_POST["item"];
        }
    }
}
}
```

and to show the cart elements I use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['item'])){
   foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $row){
...
}
?>
```

I'm trying to remove this elements using `unset()` but it doesn't work. I need your advice and also here I have 3 prices for 3 size 'Small, Medium, Large'. How can O do it like that to show the total on the cart?
Please, any idea?

Comment: So many `if`s. Learn to make better use of `&&`.

Comment: Is the code for a real productive system? I hope not! Your approach is totaly wrong! Please make a proper research before coding "something"...

Comment: @bub yes its for a friend store,i just put a small part of the code i have 3 conditions for every size thats why. please can you tell me what is totaly wrong so i can fix it?and hope anyone have an advice for the question i asked. Thanks,